# Is there a way to create a class from a sql table using visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like to create a c# class definition from a SQL table in Visual Studio 2010.

In Server Explorer I have added a data connection and can browse to the table. This shows me the table definition, but I can't find a way to right click and "generate class".

Is this possible? If not any tool that can do this quickly? I just need 1 class generated from 1 table.

Thanks

EDIT I should also mention I plan to populate this strongly typed collection using ADO.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a LINQ to SQL project, connect to that database then in the LINQtoSQL browser you'll be able to drag tables into the .dbml diagram and LINQtoSQL will generate a class for you that represents the table along with a class that represents each row in the table.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Comment: That worked, but it also created a functional object with insert/update/delete methods, and it uses a partial class structure, semi difficult to maintain. Still it was a quick easy solution.

Comment: LINQ to SQL is an ORM and like most ORMs it will generate more than just a POCO.  You might look at Entity Framework as well as LINQ to SQL is no longer being worked on at microsoft.